# Confusion about torsors and surjective morphisms

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and $X$ be a smooth projective integral $k$-variety, and $G$ be a finite abelian group scheme over $X$. We know that an element of the etale cohomology group $H^1(X,G)$ is a class of a torsor $Y \rightarrow X$ under $G$. Since we are working over an algebraically closed field, we see that $Y$ has a $k$-rational point and so in some sense $Y$ "looks like" $G$. But this means that the torsor $Y$ corresponds to the trivial torsor and so wouldn't $H^1(X,G)$ be the trivial group since any $Y$ would have a $k(=\bar{k})$-point? I know this has to be false but where did I understand wrongly? **EDIT. $Y(X)$ has to be non-empty to ensure $Y \cong G$, not $Y(k)$, so clearly $H^1(X,G)$ cannot be trivial all the time.**

Also, such a torsor $Y$ would be an abelian covering of $X$, so it is surjective. If $X$ is a group variety, and $Y$ is the trivial torsor, we would get a surjective (homo)morphism of group varieties. But if $G$ is "small", say $\mu_n$, and $X$ is "big", say an abelian $m$-fold, how would $G \rightarrow X$ ever be surjective? In what sense?

Comment: Do you mean that $G$ is a scheme over $X$? $Y$ would be trivial if it is isomorphic to $G$ as a scheme over $X$ with its $G$-action.

Comment: @cgb5436 Yes I just had a quick look at Milne EC and realised I wrote it wrongly.

Comment: Yep! That's what I was looking at! Page 120 :)

Comment: @cgb5436 Oh then I think $Y(X)$ has to be non-empty to actually be isomorphic to $G$, not $Y(k)$... OK so the first doubt is cleared i guess... Thanks!

Comment: Re: the second half of your question, $Y$ is not supposed to look like $G$ even locally. The *fibers* of the map $Y \to X$ are supposed to look like $G$ (locally); $Y$ itself is supposed to look like $X \times G$ equipped with the projection to $X$ (locally). If you have background in algebraic topology "$G$-torsor" is another way to say "principal $G$-bundle."

Comment: @QiaochuYuan The definition of principal bundle helped me understand better what $Y$ exactly is. In this case I suppose we cannot consider the covering $Y \rightarrow X$ to be a morphism between algebraic groups right? Not sure why in the literature when $X$ is a group variety, these abelian coverings are called *isogenies*.